# Unity Restsharp Api Json Serialization & Deserialization

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, backend, restsharp

I am developing a multiplayer game. I have a friend who developing API on Swagger.io . So here is my problem:

I want to use Task function that I can use instead of Unity's own UnityWebRequest function.
I look After doing some research, I wrote the following codes.

```
    private async Task<T> Send<T>(string service, object obj)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(service)
    {
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
        Method = Method.POST,
    };
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        uniqueID = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
        platform = "1";
#endif
#if UNITY_IOS
        uniqueID = UIDevice.identifierForVendor
        platform = "0";
#endif
        request.AddHeader("DeviceID", uniqueID);
        request.AddHeader("BundleID", Application.identifier);
        request.AddHeader("BuildID", "0");
        request.AddHeader("Platform", platform);
        request.AddHeader("Version", "0");
        request.AddJsonBody(obj);

        var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

        if (response.Content != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var jsonSerializerSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore };
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content, jsonSerializerSetting);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return default;
        }
```

Since it is an async function, I call it with await without any problems. Like this :

I have some class that can response some other class :

```
[Serializable]
public class WelcomeRequest : Response
{
    public string Location;
    public string Language;
}
[Serializable]
public class WelcomeRequest : Response
{
    public string Location;
    public string Language;
}[Serializable]
public class WelcomeResponse : Response
{
    public WelcomePayload Payload;
}

[Serializable]
public class WelcomePayload : Response
{
    public Player Player;
    public Settings Settings;
    public Season Play;
    public Season Purchase;
    public Game GameOfSeason;
    public Game[] Games;
    public double PrizePool;
}
```

(I know it's a big project and there are a lot of subclasses. I don't want you to write code for me, I just want you to explain the logic of the code I wrote and an example that I can reference. Not to mention that I'm trying to do it alone. I don't have any friends who can help you but you.)
I am able to receive files in json format from the server. But since this function only returns the object, I cannot assign sub-objects of the class. Do I need to convert it to json format again and deserialize it? Since I was working with the Firebase infrastructure before, I was able to communicate without any problems. I looked for Restsharp Unity tutorials but couldn't find any. Can you help me? At least if you guide me I will try to solve it myself. I'm sorry if I didn't express myself properly as this is my first post on this site and I don't know the rules very well.
Endless thanks to all of you.

Comment: I don't understand your question ... `But since this function only returns the object, I cannot assign sub-objects of the class.` .. why not? If this returns let's say a `WelcomeResponse` what hinders you from accessing e.g. the `Payload.Player` etc ...?

Comment: I can get datas from server. For example Language = ENG, LanguageCode = 0, LanguageFlag = ENGFLAG etc. I can get datas but when i try to set default language from for example Localization class (includes the above information lik LanguageCode ) I cannot parse the json file. Since I kept it as an array, I listed that problem as an array and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question but you might want to consider using a generated client.

If the API is made in swagger you should be able to make a C# API client using  [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) and the  Swagger Schema. Then just build the generated project and drop the DLL in the unity projects Assets folder.

You probably also need to include [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) and [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Just download these NuGet packages and unpack them (nupkg files are just zips) the dll should be in there. Include it by dropping the DLL in the Assets folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I guess I had a hard time because I don't know how to create the swagger scheme. RestSharp and Newtonsoft.Json dlls are already present in my project. I wasn't having any problems pulling data, but I couldn't synchronize the values ​​in the classes from the server because I didn't pull data according to the schema. Lights are on in my head right now. Thanks for the shortcut. I will try and test it and share the results (hopefully) positively with the codes.